# How To Parallelize The Following Loop?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to run my function in parallel, however all examples contain only an `i` variable. I tried to apply all methods in [Parallel for Loop in Python](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/parallel-for-loops-python/).

One of my function is below. If I can solve problem for this function, I can handle other functions too.

```
def forlooptest(testX,N,kernel_matrix):
    for i in range(0,10000):
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print(i)
        for j in range(0,3):
            img = testX[i,:,:,j]
            filtered_img = sr_cnn(img,N,kernel_matrix)
            testX_new[i,:,:,j]= filtered_img.astype(np.uint8)
    return testX_new
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Had you tried threading ?
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/
Maybe this helps you

Comment: You appear to be using third-party modules like maybe pandas or numpy. If so, at a minimum, please tag your question with them.

Comment: @Ojas_Gupta: Thank you for your suggestion, it is very helpful and I solved my problem.

Comment: What's `sc_cnn()`? Maybe you can vectorize it?